# cloudwatch metric alarms period over period

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I'm relatively new to cloudwatch, but I'm not seeing a native ability to do something like alarming when a metric is changed substantially vs its value some amount of time ago.

As an example: total number of documents indexed in elasticsearch dropped more than 50% vs the count an hour ago.

(Note: anomaly detection seems close but isn't quite what I'm looking for; doesn't allow for much configuration other than standard deviations.)

Is there such a capability in cloudwatch metric alarms, and if so, how can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You can use metric MATH function **RATE** which will return the rate of change of the metric per second. This is calculated as the difference between the latest data point value and the previous data point value, divided by the time difference in seconds between the two values. To know more, Kindly refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html#:%7E:text=%E2%9C%93-,RATE,-TS)

Comment: This is helpful, though admittedly 'rate (per second)' isn't quite the same as what I'm looking for. I was hoping for 'vs this same time yesterday' or 'vs this same time an hour ago' as opposed to 'exactly the previous data point'. But I can probably work with this.